# How to list NuGet packages used in my project programatically with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

In order to print them in the legal info of the app, I'd like to recover all the used packages in the app along with their version and the repo that contains them.

So, is there anything within the framework that allows me to recover programmatically (from c#) the info you see on the Nuget Package Manager for each package in the project?

This is the info that we would like:

[image: the Info you see on the Nuget Package Manager]

But only the name, version, and Project URL would be alright too...

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the needed information from YourProject.csproj file.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't programmatically have access to this file. Do you know a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

even you can use NuGet Server API for get extra information [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview)